# Two way communication is returning error in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to send messages between `contentscript` and `background script` like below

**ContentScript.js**

```
 chrome.extension.sendMessage({ type : "some" }, function(response) {
    anotherFunction( response.data );
    return true;        
 });
 function anotherFunction(data){
    // Some code here
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({ type : "someOther" }, function(response) {
         console.log( response.data ); // Failed to get Response
         return true;       
    });
 }
```

**Background.js**

```
 chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
   switch(request.type){
       case "some":
            sendResponse({ data : "Some Response" });
            return true;
       break;
       case "someOther":
            // Here I am getting an error. Error is given below
            sendResponse({ data : "Some Response" });
       break;
   }
 });
```

**Error**
 Could not send response: The chrome.runtime.onMessage listener must return true if you want to send a response after the listener returns

How can I fix this issue.?

Comment: Have you tried adding a `return true` in your second `case` like the error message suggests?

Comment: @apsillers Yes it is working fine. I had to put return true in two places but I had put in only one place.. That was the issue. Thanks for pointing out. Could you please post it as answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    ...
    return true; //Important
});
```

In your case you forgot to add the return in the second `case`.

Comment: I'm kinda wondering on what does `return true` actually does in this case?

Comment: See the notes at the bottom of the section: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#simple
(TLDR Async vs sync usage)