# Can't pass parent function argument to child anonymous function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, scope, arguments, anonymous-function

In one of the background files of my chrome extension I'm checking for cookies and ran into a problem. In my function `chrome.cookies.get({"url": domain, "name": name},function(cookie) {});` I am able to get the cookie object and pass it into the last parameter (an anonymous function) as the variable *cookie* and access it's value with *cookie.value*.

The problem is that I am only able to send a return response from the parent function and not the nested anonymous function from within the `chrome.cookies.get` call.

In my example below I am able to return a response (verified with an alert on another page) with **value1** but **value2** is never being returned... After doing a lot of reading I think I narrowed down the problem to a scoping error... By that I mean my response call **sendResponse** (a parameter in the parent function) is not being accessed by the nested anonymous function.

```
function getCookies(request, sender, sendResponse, domain, name) {
    chrome.cookies.get({"url": domain, "name": name}, function(cookie) {
            sendResponse({"myvar":"value2"}); //DOES NOT WORK
            if(cookie){
                anotherFunction(cookie.value);
            }else{
                anotherFunction("0");
            }
    });
    sendResponse({"myvar":"value1"});  // WORKS
}
```

So basically, I just need to figure out some method to push my **sendResponse** parameter down to the anonymous function; or re-create a similar method that would not cause this scoping issue. Any assistance or guidance with this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 3):

In reference to this issue [Two way communication is returning error in Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16419563/two-way-communication-is-returning-error-in-chrome-extension), did you returned true at the end of your *onMessage* listener? Worked in my case.

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) { 
  // your getCookies call
  return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. How about forcing `sendResponse` into the cookie?

```
function getCookies(request, sender, sendResponse, domain, name) {
  Object.prototype.sendResponse=sendResponse;

  chrome.cookies.get({"url": domain, "name": name}, function(cookie) {
    cookie.sendResponse({"myvar":"value2"});
    if(cookie){
      anotherFunction(cookie.value);
    }else{
      anotherFunction("0");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I tried that earlier, and even when I added the `var sendResponse=arguments[1];` line you suggested **value2** is still not being returned through sendResponse.

Comment: Please see the edit. I forgot the method calling the callback would not be aware of the second argument. Making it global should work. Also have you tried it with the value1 code removed?

Comment: I tried your updated version and still no response from sendResponse. I like your idea of trying to use a global; do you think it may have anything to do because this is running in the **background script** of my chrome extension? I believe that means it's running in context of my extension itself and not the window page... Also to double check code is actually being executed I've been periodically commenting in/out the send *value1* line.

Comment: Also just as a further update; `window.sendResponse({"myvar":"value2"});` works in context of the outer function, but still not for the nested anonymous function.

Comment: Yeah I think the background process may not be in window the way I expect it. See the edit for yet another approach.

Comment: I tried the update; and still no response. I feel this has to be some strange specific problem with the way chrome extensions work.

Comment: yeah you got me i dont know enough about chrome extensions to continue troubleshooting this one

Answer (score 0):

Having completely not tested it, is there any reason you can't pass in a named callback instead?:

```
function getCookies(request, sender, sendResponse, domain, name) {
  var cb = function(cookie) {
    sendResponse({"myvar":"value2"});
    if(cookie){
      anotherFunction(cookie.value);
    }else{
      anotherFunction("0");
    }
  };
  chrome.cookies.get({"url": domain, "name": name}, cb);
  sendResponse({"myvar":"value1"});  // WORKS
}
```

`sendResponse` should still be in scope when `cb` gets called, no?

Comment: I tried and still no response from sendResponse. I'm not sure why there would be a difference whether I defined it within `chrome.cookies.get` or above. But I think the scoping issue could either be because the function is within the cookie call; or it's because the function is anonymous... Do you think somehow replacing the anonymous function with a normal one could work?

Answer (score 0):

(I was just about to ask about it too, but I found your question)

just do this:

```
chrome.cookies.get({"url":"https://...","name":"..."}, function(cookie){
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(sender.tab.id, {"cookie": cookie.value});
  });
```

p.s. next time try adding [[image]google-chrome-extension](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extension) tag to your questions.